# spring-amqp transaction semantics

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am currently testing a rather simple example concerning messaging transactions in connection with database transactions with spring amqp.

The use case is as follows:

- message is received
- a message is sent
- database is updated

  ```
  @Transactional
  public void handleMessage(EventPayload event) {
      MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
      entity.setName(event.getName());

      rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("myExchange", "payload.create", payload);

      MyEntity savedEntity = entityRepository.save(entity);
  }
  ```

The expected behavior in case of a failure during the database operation is that the received message is rolled back to the bus (DefaultRequeueRejected = false) and goes into a dead letter queue. Also the message sent should be rolled back.

I can achieve this with the following configuration:

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer subscriberListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                              MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter,
                                                              PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(SUBSCRIBER_QUEUE_NAME);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        container.setChannelTransacted(true);
        container.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        return container;
    }
```

So this works fine - what I do not understand is that the observed behavior is exactly the same if I do not set the transaction manager on the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. So if I configure the following the bebavior does not change:

```
@Bean
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer subscriberListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                  MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(SUBSCRIBER_QUEUE_NAME);
            container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
            container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
            return container;
        }
```

Can someone explain what is happening there? Why is the second case also working? What is different internally if the `PlatformTransactionManager` is registered on the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `transactionManager` is your database tm, since your listener is `@Transactional`, there's not a lot of difference for these scenarios.

In the first case, the transaction is started by the container before the listener is invoked (actually before the message is retrieved from an internal queue so a transaction will start even if there's no message).

In the second case, the transaction is started by the transaction interceptor when we invoke the listener.

Consider the case where the listener is not transactional, but some downstream component is; let's say the listener invokes that component successfully, then does some more work before throwing an exception. In that case, the DB commit would be successful and the message rejected. This might not be the desired behavior, especially if messages are requeued. In cases like this, it's generally better to synchronize the rabbit transaction with the database transaction by injecting the database tm.

In your case, there is little chance of a failure between the db commit and the rabbit ack so this really doesn't apply in your case and you don't need a tm in the container.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Regarding your last sentence in the answer. What can actually go wrong between db commit and the rabbit ack?

Comment: Since there's only framework code there will be no code failures in that time. However, if, say, the connection to rabbitmq is lost, before the ack is sent, your rabbit template operation will roll back and the message will be requeued, but your DB transaction is committed. This applies in the other scenario too, so you should always have code to handle duplicate deliveries.